# Does fread work,when you want the elements in blocks?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

size_t file_size(FILE *fd){
    if (fd == NULL) {
        printf("File not found");
        return -1;
    }
    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);    
    return ftell(fd);
}

int main() {
    FILE *in;
    FILE *out;

    char buffer[2] = { 0 };
    int n = 0;
    in = fopen("test.txt", "rb");
    if (in == NULL) {
        printf("cona\n"); return -1;
    }

    out = fopen("out.txt", "wb");
    if (out == NULL) {
        printf("cona1\n"); return -1;
    }

    size_t size = file_size(in);
    for(n = 0; n < size; n += 2){
        if (fread(&buffer, sizeof(char), 2, in) !=2) {
            printf("cona2 \n");
        } //keeps given erros in here
        fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(char), 2, out);
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    }
    printf(" \n in: %zu \n", size);
    printf(" \n out: %zu \n", file_size(out));

    fclose(out);
    fclose(in);
    system("PAUSE");
    return(0);
}
```

My main question in here is if fread fuction works in a cycle, and if i can ask just n numbers of element in the file ervytime, and not the all file at once, i try this but it keeps me given error reading the file, it doesn't read anything.

Comment: Where's C++ in this question? I can't see any, in the given code.

Comment: `return -1;` but the function has type `size_t` which is unsigned. That will cause havoc in `main` because you do not check its validity anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem after your function finds the file size with

```
fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
return ftell(fd);
```

because you do not rewind to the start of the file before trying to read from it.

```
rewind(fd);
```

or

```
fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Wow, I've never been a bruh.  Is that worth a silver medal or a gold?  :)